# Can't unmount /tmp, fuser output empty

Tags: partitioning, mount, tmp, umount

my `/tmp` shrank to 1MB because there were no free space on `/home` device. Now I need to expand this, so the first thing to do is to unmount the device. But that's what happens when I try:

`~ $ df
Filesystem        1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2          14287460 13555104         0 100% /
none                      4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                1955772       12   1955760   1% /dev
tmpfs                394200     1160    393040   1% /run
none                   5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                1971000      152   1970848   1% /run/shm
none                 102400       36    102364   1% /run/user
overflow               1024        0      1024   0% /tmp
/dev/sda5          23899004  6243984  16417980  28% /home
/home/ja/.Private  23899004  6243984  16417980  28% /home/ja
 ~ $ fuser /tmp
 ~ $ sudo umount /tmp
umount: /tmp: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))`

`fuser` output is empty, there are no devices mounted inside /tmp, so I suppose this shouldn't be happening. What's wrong then?

Answer (score 0):

```
fuser /tmp
```

only shows processes belonging to your current user accessing `/tmp/`. It doesn't show processes belonging to other users, and it doesn't show processes just accessing files inside `/tmp/`.

Use

```
sudo fuser -m /tmp/
```

to show any processes accessing any file on the file system mounted on `/tmp/`.

Comment: This one's output is empty too.